# Android SDK - Open any file I want?

Tags: android, file, sdk, io

According to the Android Development Documentation, you can't just open any file you want (["Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)).

What, however, when I want my application to read files created by other applications? Let's say I have a file in /data/app_1/hello.txt, but my application has nothing to do with it because my app is called app_2, how would I still be able to open this file (and write back to it)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't in general, Applications on Android are isolated and sparated. A application can only write and read its own files.

There are exceptions: As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) states: "It's possible to arrange for two applications to share the same Linux user ID, in which case they are able to access each other's files. To conserve system resources, applications with the same user ID can also arrange to run in the same Linux process and share the same VM (the applications must also be signed with the same certificate)."

Another possiblity is that the files are created as "world readable" so that every application can read it.

So to summarize and come back to your question: If you can not modify "my_app_1" then it is impossible. Of you can modify both applications choose one of the solutions above.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. If you are designing both applications and want to share the file, keep it somewhere else (for example - external storage) or make it world readable.
2. If you are trying to read another app's file - well, you shouldn't, that's a key element in the android security architecture.

Comment: The reason is that I want to create a savegame manager, so users can easily move savegames from one device to the other. In order to do this, I will need to get access to the files though.

Comment: Your motivation is one thing, which is not bad at all, but there are other (malicious) motives to some people, which Android has to protect from.

Comment: See my answer, thats possible if you can modify your "game" application for which you are writing the "savegame manager".

Comment: But it should be possible, because there are apps that can browse through directories and read/write. For example there's ES File Explorer, which doesn't even require root.